# Correctly writed in Db, but "Illegal operation on empty result set." error by Sql

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server

I'm making an `INSERT` on a sql database. And a strange thing happens: when I run the downer code, the DB is correctly writed but the compiler give me an error of

`java.sql.SQLException: Illegal operation on empty result set.`

I've yet searched about it and I found that it may due to a bug of JDBC driver (but I don't think so). So I decided to post here.

Firstly I give you database tables:

table subject

```
+------------------+----------------+------------+
| subjectCode      | SubjectName    | teacherCode|
+------------------+----------------+------------+
| 1                | Maths          | 10         |
| 2                | English        | 20         |
| 3                | Greek          | 30         |
+------------------+----------------+------------+
```

table class

```
+------------------+----------------+
| ClassCode        | ClassName      |
+------------------+----------------+
| 1                | Class1         |
| 2                | Class2         |
| 3                | Class3         |
+------------------+----------------+
```

table lesson (row and col are the rows (hours) and columns (days) of a timetable, that univocally determine the lesson in timetable; for example: hour 1 is the first hour of the day)

```
+------------------+----------------+------------+-----------+-------+-------+
| LessonCode       | SubjectCode    | teacherCode| ClassCode |  Day  |  Hour |
+------------------+----------------+------------+-----------+-------+-------+
| 1                | James          | 10         |     1     |   1   |   1   |
| 2                | John           | 20         |     2     |   1   |   2   |
| 3                | Frank          | 30         |     3     |   1   |   3   |
+------------------+----------------+------------+-----------+-------+-------+
```

Code:

```
private void writeLesson(String subjectName, String className, int column, int row)
{
    try{
        int subjCode;
        String query="SELECT subjectCode from subject WHERE subjectName='"+subjectName+"';";
        rs = st.executeQuery(query);
        rs.next();
        subjCode  = rs.getInt("subjectCode");


        int teacherCode;
        String query1="SELECT teacherCode from subject WHERE subjectName='"+subjectName+"';";
        rs = st.executeQuery(query1);
        rs.next();
        teacherCode = rs.getInt("teacherCode");

        int classCode;
        String query2="SELECT classCode from class WHERE className='"+className+"';";
        rs = st.executeQuery(query2);
        rs.next();
        ClassCode = rs.getInt("classCode");


        String query3 ="INSERT INTO lesson (subjCode, classCode, teacherCode, day, hour) "
                + "VALUES ('" + subjCode + "',"
                + "'" + classCode + "',"
                + "'" + teacherCode + "',"
                + "'" + column + "',"
                + "'" + row + "');";
        PreparedStatement statement=con.prepareStatement(query3);
        statement.executeUpdate();
        statement.close();   
    }

    catch (Exception ex){
        System.out.println("Error db: "+ex);
```

**IMPORTANT** : the method `writeLesson` is in a `cycle`. I've tested this code not in a cycle and it works. Why In your opinion?

**SOLUTION** : the problem was that in the cycle in which is the method `writeLesson` I passed to it "blank" strings, causing the error (that's why writing on DB worked, but there were errors).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you checked the result sets from your select statements? Isn't one of them empty? rs.getInt() will throw this exception, if rs is empty (rs.next() returns false in this case)

Comment: Hi and thanks for trying to help me. I explain you: I've tried every of the three parts of the code separately and they work. But if I try as I write up, nothing, there is the error. The only difference is that in native code, the method `writeLesson` is in a loop, so it is called many than one time

Comment: Your comment illumined me (or maybe 8 hours ago I was too tired . . .). The problem was that I considered "blank" cell with no lesson and I wanted to write it on DB. This explained also why the writing on DB worked. thank you